# How to enable functions in script from what is specified in configuration file?

Tags: python, json, configuration

I have the following JSON file:

```
{
    "add1":true,
    "add2":false,
    "add3":true
}
```

And the following Python programm:

```py
def add1(n): return n+1
def add2(n): return n+2
def add3(n): return n+3

def score(n):
    with open('file.json', 'r') as f:
        conf = json.load(f)
        for key, value in conf.items()
            if value == True:
                # add1 and add3 calls only because they're set to True
                return (add1(n) + add3(n))
```

As written in the code I would like to call the functions only if there are set as True in the configuration JSON file. Is it the right way to proceed? Do existing tools ease this approach or do I have to write each case manually?

Comment: What do you want to happen if something like `"screw_it":true` appear in the configuration file? What if neither `"add1":true` nor `"add1":false` are there?

Comment: @Goyo I might raise an error I would have caught but I expect the user not to mess with it and put the boolean value I'll indicate.

Comment: Then try something like what @S.Pellegrino [proposes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56597722/2142055). It is safer and more maintainable than using `eval` or `globals()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
import json

def add1(n): return n+1
def add2(n): return n+2
def add3(n): return n+3

defs = {
    'add1' : add1,
    'add2' : add2,
    'add3' : add3
}

def score(n):
   with open('file.json', 'r') as f:
       conf = json.load(f)
       return sum(function(n) for name, function in defs.items() if conf[name])
```

If you are ok with lambdas, you could even use:

```
defs = {
    'add1' : lambda n: n+1,
    'add2' : lambda n: n+2,
    'add3' : lambda n: n+3
}
```

Comment: I used your solution, it works well, thank you very much!

Comment: I am thinking the `return` statement would be happier living outside the `with` block. It has nothing to do there.

Answer (score 3):

You can replace your for loop with a call to `eval`

```
def score(n):
    with open('file.json', 'r') as file:
        conf = json.load(file)
        return sum(eval(f"{k}({n})") if v else 0 for k, v in conf.items())
```

This assumes that all entries in your json map to an existing function

Comment: My add functions were a pretext for a more complex problem and I reduced it to an understandable one; my first aim was only to call different functions which take a string in argument and return a `double` value. But it does not seem to work with a string, does the eval method work with string given as argument?

Comment: @ooj-001 - All eval does is take whatever you put inside it and try and run it as python code, so yes

Comment: Ok thank you, also is your `f` specific to the syntax of what has to be written in the `eval` function or have you mispelled with file? Because in my editor the way the letter `f` is highlighted makes it so that it is understood as a string.

Answer (score 1):

You should use eval: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval

```
def score(n):
   with open('file.json', 'r') as f:
       conf = json.load(f)
       sum = 0
       for key, value in conf.items():
           if value == True:
               sum += eval('{}({})'.format(key, n))
       return sum
```

Answer (score 1):

@Sayse had a good method although I'd change the sum line so that we don't need to add 0 for when the value is false.

```
            return sum(eval(f"{key}({n})") for key, value in conf.items() if value)
```

Or the other way to call a function named by a string is

```
            return sum(globals()[k](n) for k,v in conf.items() if v)
```

I'm not certain if best practices in Python favour one version or the other. The results are identical.

*Note that you are trusting the data to specify the functions called by your program. Incorrect or malicious data could cause indeterminate and harmful behaviour, so you might want to check the keys to make sure they are all specifying one of the functions that you intend to use in this way.*

Comment: I will parse the value in the configuration file and raise exception if something happens, thank you for your answer.